# How to check who's performing the action from within a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Is there a way to figure out which account is used to perform an update on a table?

Basically, we have some automated process that updates a table on a regular interval. Unfortunately, this process is not documented and we are trying to figure out who's making the change. In order to do that, I was thinking of using a trigger on the table to detect the "rogue" update. I know this is far from ideal, but I think it could be the shortest path to figure what's happening without killing the prod...

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: have you tried with system_user function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `system_user` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logging_tr
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO logging_table (logger_user, logged_date)
VALUES (SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE();
END;
```